# Como usar LocalStorage em um componente funcional React

Tags: react, localstorage, componentes, react-hooks

**Como posso usar LocalStorage nesse caso**

**do jeito que fiz funciona apenas com componente de classe**

> Erro que aparece é: TypeError: repositories is not a function

```
    export default function Main() {

    const [newRepo, setNewRepo] = useState('');
    const [repositories, setRepositories] = useState([]);
    const [clearInput] = useState([]);
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        repositories(localStorage.getItem('repositories'));

        if (repositories) {
            setRepositories(JSON.parse(repositories));
        }
    }, [repositories]);

    useEffect((_, prevState) => {
        if (prevState.repositories !== repositories) {
            localStorage.setItem('repositories', JSON.stringify(repositories));
        }
    });
```

Comment: O que você quer dizer na linha `repositories(localStorage.getItem('repositories'));`? Não faz sentido nenhum. Seria `setRepositories`?

Answer (score -1):

```js
const App = () => {
  const [repositories, setRepositories] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const repositoriesLocal = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('repositories'));

    setRepositories(repositoriesLocal)
  }, [])

  return <div>
    {repositories.map(item => <li>{item.name}</li>)}
  </div>;
};
```

Comment: Matheus, sua pergunta seria de qualidade se, além do código, você descrevesse sobre qual foi o erro que o usuário cometeu. Assim você permite uma compreensão maior do problema por parte de quem pergunta e torna o conhecimento reaproveitável. Só postar o código incentiva nada além de um `ctrl + C` e `ctrl + V` Espero te ver muito por aqui ainda ajudando a comunidade da melhor forma possível. Abraços!